# Fully Justifying text in Overleaf Template

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, text

I am currently using an OVerleaf template to prepare my Cover Letter https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-cover-letter/yhdwrhyvqjwy

I am unable to justify the paragraphs fully. I tried using the `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}` and `\justifying`, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. If you want your document to be justified, then why do you use `Ragged2e`?

Comment: the tex default is justification, why not use something simple and easily customised like `\documentclass{article}` rather than starting from some "template" setting up a different, ragged right, layout that you don't want?

Comment: I just looked.... `cover.cls` is only a few lines, many of them are simply wrong, like `\centering{`  but it uses `\raggedright`  repeatedly in almost all commands with no central way to customise that, so if you really want to use this (I wouldn't) just add `\renewcommand\raggedright{}` so it does nothing.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am new to LaTex. I tried the `Ragged2e` simply by a few google searches on this topic.

@DavidCarlisle- By using the `\documentclass{article]`, the entire page gets messed up. It there a way to get texts justified simply by small tweaks in the current `cover.cls`?

Answer (score 0):

Add before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\lettercontent}[1]{\noindent\justifying\fontspec[Path = OpenFonts/fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{13pt}\selectfont {#1 \\}\mbox{}\\ \normalfont}
```

[image: a]